# clpfd - constraint upper bond of domain the be the maximum of a list of elements

Tags: prolog, clpfd

Given the following code:

```
solve(G,L) :-
    G = [A0,B0,C0,D0],
    L = [A1,B1,C1,D1,A2,B2,C2,D2,A3,B3,C3,D3,A4,B4,C4,D4],
    G ins 0..4,
    L ins 0..max(G).
```

I want to constraint L to not contain values that are higher than the maximum value contained in G, but I get a "domain error" when using this syntax. Is there another way to express this?

Comment: Does `G` always have a length of four?

Comment: Yes, max value in G is 4 and is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you were on the right track. But `L ins 0..max(G)` does not work, because the bounds that you pass to `ins/2` need to be integers or `inf` or `sup`.

[SWI-Prolog clpfd manual page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) supports `max` in
finite domain arithmetic expressions, so we first state that `MaxG` is the maximum of `A0`, `B0`, `C0`, and `D0`. Then we state that `MaxG` is greater than or equal to each item in list `L`.

Putting it all together:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

gte_than(X,Y) :-
    X #>= Y.

solve(G,L) :-
    G = [A0,B0,C0,D0],
    L = [A1,B1,C1,D1,A2,B2,C2,D2,A3,B3,C3,D3,A4,B4,C4,D4],
    G ins 0..4,
    L ins 0..sup,
    MaxG #= max(max(A0,B0),max(C0,D0)),
    maplist(gte_than(MaxG),L).
```

Here are some queries:

```
?- solve([0,1,2,1], [0,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,1,1,2]).
true.

?- solve([0,1,2,1], [0,3,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,1,1,2]).
false.

?- solve([0,3,2,1], [0,3,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,1,1,2]).
true.

?- solve([0,3,2,1], [0,3,2,1,1,2,4,4,1,0,1,2,1,1,1,2]).
false.

?- solve([4,3,2,1], [0,3,2,1,1,2,4,4,1,0,1,2,1,1,1,2]).
true.
```

---

Side note: SICStus Prolog has a specialized [arithmetic constraint](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Arithmetic-Constraints.html) named `maximum/2` we could use here, but that constraint is not (yet) available in clpfd with SWI-Prolog.

Comment: I forgot to specify that I use SWI-Prolog. Does this still apply?

Comment: +1! If your system does not have `maximum/2`, I suggest the following definition of `list_max/2`: Auxiliary predicate: `max_(L, Max0, Max) :- Max #= max(L, Max0).` and main predicate: `list_max([L|Ls], Max) :- foldl(max_, Ls, L, Max).`. This gives you `list_max/2`, relating a list of CLP(FD) expressions to its maximum value, in every system that supports `max/2`.

Comment: Thanks, the solution works! I just get this warning: 
`Warning: c:/.../strata.pro:10: Test is always true: var(MaxG)`  and I was wondering what it is about?